# Javascript Click/Drag and Select Table rows and columns

Tags: javascript, xhtml, user-interface

I am wondering if anyone knows a java script library that would add a "select" type of functionality as seen in excel/google docs where you can click and select several different parts of a row and/or column.  I am looking at adding this functionality to my web application.  Does anyone know where of library's preferably in java script that will be able to add this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a plugin called pfSelect which provides the kind of functionality that I think you are looking for. You could take a look at that. And if you're not using jQuery, I'm pretty sure that every major JS ui library has this kind of functionality (Dojo's Grid, ExtJS' ArrayGrid, YUI's DataTable, etc.).